# echo "Hello World" > /dev/stdout prints nothing

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, cygwin

Scenario:

```
$ echo "Hello World" > /dev/stderr
Hello World

$ echo "Hello World" > /dev/stdout

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 xxx 3.3.4(0.341/5/3) 2022-01-31 19:35 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Why `echo "Hello World" > /dev/stdout` prints nothing? How to troubleshot?

UPD.

> Does `echo "Hello World"` print normally?

Yes:

```
$ echo "Hello World"
Hello World
```

> If not, did you invoke `exec >/dev/null` or similar in the shell maybe?

No.

UPD2. Found where it stopped working:

```
$ clang t554.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c -S -O3 -o /dev/stdout
        .text
        <asm code>

# "exxxtern" was a typo
$ clang t554.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c -S -O3 -o /dev/stdout
t554.c:6:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exxxtern'
                exxxtern int xxx;
                ^
1 error generated.


TASKING+pavel.morozkin@SPBPC023 ~
$ clang t554.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c -S -O3 -o /dev/stdout
# nothing is printed for the 1st time
```

UPD3. I can reproduce it with clang on another machine:

```
$ clang t455.c -S -o /dev/stdout
        .text
        <asm code>

# introduce the error

$ clang t455.c -S -o /dev/stdout
t455.c:26:1: error: unknown type name 'x'
x
^
t455.c:26:2: error: expected identifier or '('
x
 ^
2 errors generated.

# fix the error

$ clang t455.c -S -o /dev/stdout
# nothing is printed

$ clang --version
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
```

Comment: In any case, doing `> /dev/stdout` / `> /dev/stderr` would be wrong if the intention was to print on stdout or stderr. To print on stdout: `echo Hello World` (that's where `echo` writes its output). To print to stderr: `echo >&2 Hello World` (`echo` still writes to its stdout, but it has been redirected to the same *open file description* as opened on stderr). See also `print -u2 Hello World` in the ksh/zsh shells where `print` does in that case write to its stderr.

Comment: On GNU/Linux systems, `/dev/stdout` is a symbolic link pointing to `/proc/self/fd/1`. The `/proc` directory is usually a mountpoint to a [proc file system (procfs)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html#process-specific-subdirectories), and this particular subdirectory points to the process reading the file system. Indeed, on a real GNU/Linux system, `echo "Hello, World" > /dev/stdout` outputs `Hello, World`. [Cygwin website](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html) doesn't mention anything specific, aside from `/proc`/`/dev` being an emulation.

Comment: (1) Does `echo "Hello World"` print normally? (2) If not, did you invoke `exec >/dev/null` or similar in the shell maybe?

Comment: Works for me (`bash` and `sh`). Same `uname -a` result.  In my case the `/dev/std{out,err}` devices are symlinks to `/proc/self/fd/{1,2}` respectively. Output from `cd /proc/self/fd && df .` eventually returns a pseudo mount on `/proc/9932`, which corresponds to the PID 9932 of my shell

Comment: @roaima, Cygwin acts like Linux in that regard in that that `/dev/stdout` is a symlinks to the file the fd 1 is opened on. And then opening that file opens the corresponding file anew, it doesn't do the equivalent of a `dup(1)` like it does on other systems. So if fd 1 is opened on a socket for instance, it will fail, if it's open on some weird Windows-specific abstraction, it may fail in some obscure way.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm running Cygwin. I was giving information to the OP because a vanilla "works for me" is rarely useful

Comment: @roaima, I got that, but to  complement that, I was just reiterating that opening /dev/stdout was a bad idea given that those are symlinks to the files. IIRC, on cygwin, you have a choice on how the "console" is handled which may or may not be done via some sort of emulated pty for terminals.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski See UPD2. I think it somehow related to `error: use of ...` when `-o /dev/stdout` was used. How it can be related?

Comment: Are you saying that any time you run clang to compile a program and it fails with an error, /dev/stdout breaks in that terminal?

Comment: @psusi It seems that `-o /dev/stdout` coupled with `error: xxx` "permanently changed something in the system". More details: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54086.

Comment: I think the first thing a compiler does is to unlink() the existing file, which would remove the /dev/stdout symlink, then it replaces it with a regular file.  It should not matter whether you get an error or not.  What does ls -l /dev/stdout show before and after?\

Comment: @psusi If I recall correctly w/o the `error` it worked just fine. At least after: `$ ls -l /dev/stdout => -rw-r--r-- 1 xxx None 12 Feb 26 00:21 /dev/stdout`. The "before" will be later (have to reboot). And for `stderr`: `$ ls -l /dev/stderr => lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxx None 15 Oct 18  2019 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2`.

Comment: @pmor What @psusi said, you basically remove the symbolic link `/dev/stdout`. What you most likely want instead is _redirection_ instead of "write": `clang t455.c -S > /dev/stdout 2>&1`.

Comment: @Vilinkameni Yes, clang may remove the symbolic link ("If "-o" specifies a symlink, when clang successfully compiles something, it writes to the destination of the symlink, but when it fails to compile, it erases the symlink itself"). About redirection: `clang t455.c -S > /dev/stdout 2>&1` redirects what? The `-S` produces `t455.s`. I don't need `t455.s`. I need to print generated asm code on the `stdout`. How to correctly do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with clang, but from the brief skimming of its manual page, it seems what you want is not possible. Just generate a file and output it instead. You can delete the file afterwards if you are doing this from some script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This due to the issue: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54086:

> If "-o" specifies a symlink, when clang successfully compiles something, it writes to the destination of the symlink, but when it fails to compile, it erases the symlink itself.